# $A_3$: non-nilpotent group that is solvable

Tags: group-theory, galois-theory

I'm trying to prove that $A_3$, the alternating group, is non-nilpotent but solvable. I'm lost with the two towers of subgroups to show it's solvable or nilpotent. If someone can offer some advice for movement in the right direction, that'd be very helpful.

Comment: What is $A_n{}$?

Comment: $A_n$ is not solvable for $n\geq 5$ since it is simple and not of prime order.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I adjusted the typo.

Comment: $A_3$ is abelian (in fact, cyclic), so it is nilpotent.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider $A_4$ which is solvable but not nilpotent.